# Modifing element in array using for and in

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, int

Why the code:

```
lista=['1','2','3','4']
for element in lista:
    element=int(element)
```

won't work while the following code works?

```
lista=['1','2','3','4']
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i]=int(lista[i])
```

Obs: I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: ```element``` is a copy of the value, not a reference to it.

Comment: @LucasVirgili at which stage? In the `for` loop assignment, that claim is *precisely wrong*. After the `int` assignment, it's nearly right.

Comment: Why did you think the first version *would* work? You can see the difference between the two versions, so why do *you think* the first doesn't work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe only being different don't explain nothing. Besides, if i could see the difference between the two versions, i wouldn't even make this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop when you assign `int(element)` to `element`, it creates a new integer object and assigns it to name `element`.

In the second loop, you are assigning `int(lista[i])` to `lista[i]`, which updates the `i`th element of the list with that value.

This should help you understand it better.

```
>>> lista
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> i = lista[0]      # i points to first element of lista
>>> i
'1'
>>> i = 'a'           # Now i points to a new object 'a'
>>> lista             # So lista remains as it was before
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> lista[0] = 'a'    # Here we are replacing the first element of lista with 'a'
>>> lista
['a', '2', '3', '4']
```

Read up on [immutable and mutable objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python).

BTW what you want to do here is this -

```
for i, element in enumerate(lista):
    lista[i] = int(element)
```

Pythonic way to do this particular loop is to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) -

```
>>> lista=['1','2','3','4']
>>> lista = [int(element) for element in lista]
>>> lista
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It's more accurate to say it creates a new integer object and assigns it to the name `element`. See e.g. http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Answer (score 0):

This works because you assign each slot in the list to a new item:

```
lista=['1','2','3','4']
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i]=int(lista[i])
```

The below "works" but it doesn't do what you intend, because you're just assigning the elements to a variable name, then assigning a transformation to that name, and then not doing anything with it.:

```
lista=['1','2','3','4']
for element in lista:
    element=int(element)
    # try printing type(element) here to see that int actually does return an int
```